# Change execution timeout setting on azure/ windows server 2016 IIS

Tags: azure, iis, windows-server-2016

I have a web app hosted on a VM machine, Windows Server 2016 using IIS. One of the responses is taking over 90 seconds to execute and I can't seem to change the setting to keep the program alive long enough to receive the response. I have tried increasing the values of all the following parameters but so far nothing has made an impact.

```
1.) From IIS -> webapp -> advanced settings -> Limits -> Connection Timeout.

2.) From IIS -> configuration editor -> system.web/httpRuntime -> executionTimeout
                                                               -> shutdownTimeout
3.) From IIS -> webapp -> configuration  editor -> system.web.httpRuntime -> executionTimeout
                                                                          -> shutdownTimeout

4.) IIS -> Default App Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Idle Time-out
                                                -> Shutdown Timelimit
5.) IIS -> webapp -> CGI -> behaviour -> timeout
```

If it matters the VM was created from azure portal and I am using django as my backend. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those settings apply to Python based application.

If you follow Microsoft recommendation to [host Python apps on IIS via HttpPlatformHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019#configure-the-httpplatform-handler), then its [`requestTimeout` setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference#configuration-attributes) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, the page you linked shows configurations for HttpPlatform and FastCGI. I'm using FastCGI, is there something analogous for RequestTimeout in FastCGI?

Comment: @sintribuFastCGI does have its own request timeout, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/fastcgi/application/#configuration